# How to test below component in React using JEST

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs

I created a component for Download File which takes some props and download the file on button click, its has two function which call showLoader and HideLoader

**Component**: Below is component code which takes some props and created a Download button on click that user download file.

```
import React from 'react'
import FileSaver from 'file-saver'
import axios from 'axios'

const DownloadFile = (props) => {

  const { url, title, callShowLoader, callHideLoader } = props

  const callDownloadFile = () => {
    callShowLoader()
    axios.get(url, { responseType: 'blob' }).then(res => {
      const fileName = res.headers['content-disposition'].match(/\"(.*?)"/)
      const fileToDownload = new Blob([res.data], {type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=charset=utf-8'})
      FileSaver.saveAs(fileToDownload, fileName[1])
      callHideLoader()
    })
  }

  return (<button className='mck-button-primary' title={title} onClick={e => callDownloadFile()}>
            <span className={"mck-icon__download mck-icon-no-pad"} />
          </button>)
}

export default DownloadFile
```

**Test** Here i am testing the component, not able to test when user clicks on button for download, its giving callShowLoader is not function error

```
import React from 'react'
import { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme'
import DownloadFile from '../index.js'
import toJson from 'enzyme-to-json'
import axios from 'axios'

describe('<DownloadFile />', () => {
  const props = {
    callHideLoader: jest.fn(),
    callShowLoader: jest.fn(),
    title: 'Download Excel Report'
  }

  it('should render button title properly', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<DownloadFile {...props}/>)
    expect(wrapper.find('button').prop('title')).toEqual(props.title)
  })

  it('should call download file', () => {
    const callShowLoader = jest.fn()
    const wrapper = shallow(<DownloadFile {...props} callShowLoader={callShowLoader} />)
    wrapper.find('button').simulate('click')
    expect(callShowLoader).toHaveBeenCalled()
  })

  it('should match intial layout', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<DownloadFile {...props}/>)
    expect(wrapper.getElements()).toMatchSnapshot()
  })
})
```

Answer (score 4):

The onClick prop on DownloadFile is completely ignored as you don't use it in the implementation of the DownloadFile component.

Initialize callShowLoader and callHideLoader with jest.fn(), pass them to the DownloadFile component (when you initialize mountWrapper), then simulate the onClick button and test whether callShowLoader and callHideLoader were both called.

Comment: Thanks Robert, modified the code but still not working, giving error:

Comment: @Tall Paul code is updated now getting error:  /FilePath/ReactApp/core/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/test.js:22 throw err; TypeError: Cannot read property 'protocol' of undefined at isURLSameOrigin (/FilePath/ReactApp/core/node_modules/axios/lib/helpers/isURLSameOrigin.js:57:22) at dispatchXhrRequest error Command failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 2):

You're not passing `callShowLoader` as a prop in your tests, and therefore you'll get the `callShowLoader is not a function` error. Try this in your `beforeEach`

```
props = {
  callHideLoader: jest.fn(),
  callShowLoader: jest.fn(), 
  title: 'Download Excel Report'
}
```

and then in your test

```
it('should call callShowLoader upon click', () => {
  const button = mountWrapper.find('button')
  button.simulate('click')
  expect(props.callShowLoader).toHaveBeenCalled()
})
```

By the way I can't see any reason to use `mount` in those tests, `shallow` should do the work for you. I always write my shallows inside the test case to easily and fast see what the test is doing, like this

```
it('should call callShowLoader upon click', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<DownloadFile ...props />);
  const button = wrapper.find('button')
  button.simulate('click')
  expect(props.callShowLoader).toHaveBeenCalled()
})
```

And then I define pass the props that's necessary for the specific test inside the same test, to minimize the risk that the tests will break if I change something outside of the test. So in this case it would be

```
import React from 'react'
import sinon from 'sinon';
import { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme'
import DownloadFile from '../index.js'
import toJson from 'enzyme-to-json'

describe('<DownloadFile />', () => {
  const props = {
    callHideLoader: jest.fn(),
    callShowLoader: jest.fn(),
    title: '',
  };

  it('should render button title properly', () => {
    const title = 'Download Excel Report';
    const wrapper = shallow(<DownloadFile {...props} title={title} />);
    expect(wrapper.find('button').prop('title')).toEqual(title)
  })

  it('should call download file', () => {
    sinon.stub(axios, 'get').returns(Promise.resolve());
    const callShowLoader = jest.fn();
    const wrapper = shallow(<DownloadFile {...props} callShowLoader={callShowLoader} />);

    wrapper.find('button').simulate('click')
    expect(callShowLoader).toHaveBeenCalled()
    expect(axios.get.callCount).to.equal(1);
  })

  it('should match initial layout', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<DownloadFile {...props} />);
    expect(wrapper.getElements()).toMatchSnapshot()
  })
})
```

...but that's just a question of taste :-)

Comment: Thanks for response, but i am getting following error:                          /FilePath/ReactApp/core/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/test.js:22  throw err;
TypeError: Cannot read property 'protocol' of undefined    at isURLSameOrigin (/FilePath/ReactApp/core/node_modules/axios/lib/helpers/isURLSameOrigin.js:57:22)
    at dispatchXhrRequest 
error Command failed with exit code 1.

Comment: You have to stub the axios.get call. I'd recommend sinonjs and then `sinon.stub(axios, 'get');`

Comment: I've added an example of sinon stubing. Try to strip down your methods until you get a working test. Then you have to do some research to get further and write betautiful test cases. Good luck! :-)

Comment: Thanks #kontrollanten its get rid of other error showing only one, might be missing something: /Filepath/ReactApp/core/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/test.js:22  throw err;
  ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'headers' of undefined
    at _axios2.default.get.then.res (/Filepath/ReactApp/core/src/components/dcl/downloadFile/index.js:12:28)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
error Command failed with exit code 1.

Comment: You have to do some work by yourself also. Can you see somewhere in your code where you're trying to read the property `header` from an object? Actually the error message says which file and which line causing the error. I've given you a solution for your main question, the rest you have to do on your own to learn debugging. Good luck!